# possible to find i, j, k values when you only know the index of a flattened 3D array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

If I only know an element index, and the dimensions and storage order of an array, is it possible to find out the i,j,k triplet corresponding to that index?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
k = index % kDimension;
j = (index / kDimension) % jDimension
i = (index / kDimension) / jDimension
```

We can test this by reconstructing the index:

```
index = i * (jDimension * kDimension)
      + j * kDimension
      + k
```

And noting that it gives the same result (when you take integer rounding into account).